# Character ArrayList won't convert to String correctly

Tags: java, string, arraylist

If I set `userLineInput` to `[s, a, v, e]` it should output "Game Saved" but the output is "error". What am I doing wrong?

```
public ArrayList<Character> userLineInput;
public String               userLineInputToString;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Character s : userLineInput) {
    sb.append(s);
}

sb.toString = userLineInputToString;

if (userLineInputToString == "save") {
    Save.savePlayerSave();
    System.out.println("Game Saved");
} else {
    System.out.println(userLineInputToString);
}
```

But if I make,

```
}else{
System.out.println("error");}
```

the Output is "save" so it converts the Array to a String.

Comment: This doesn't even come close to compiling. Also, try and format your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always compare `string` using `equals` and not `==`

Change the line to

```
    if ("save".equals(userLineInputToString)) //To prevent null pointer, it better
    //to test equals on constants.
```

You are building string builder `sb`, and you should assign it to `userLineInputToString`.

Change the line from

```
sb.toString = userLineInputToString
```

to

```
userLineInputToString = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

change

```
sb.toString = userLineInputToString
```

to

```
userLineInputToString = sb.toString();
```

And

compare string equality with equals() method instead of ==